# How can I do to merge font attributes in css

Tags: css

```
font-size: 100%;
font-family: "Palatino Linotype",Palatino, serif;
```

The text of web page show normally,and the font is Palatino Linotype.But I merge the code like
this.

```
font:100% "Palation Linotype", Palatino, serif;
```

The font is Calibri, it means the css code doesn't work. How can I do if I want merge the `font-size` and `font-family`

Comment: Is it the spelling error Palatino vs. Palation?

Comment: Oh!I made an howler.Thank you very much.I should more careful.

Comment: It’s better to avoid the `font` shorthand, especially if you already have working code that does not use it. It has many kinds of pitfalls, like setting *all* font properties (e.g., `font-weight` and `font-style`, too) even though you did not mean to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your spelling. It works perfectly.

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kCuEN/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="abc">The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.</div>
<div class="def">The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.abc{font-size: 100%;
font-family: "Palatino Linotype",Palatino, serif;}

.def{font:100% "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, serif;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the font shorthand property, there are a few mandatory options that you have to specify or your browser will ignore the entire line, as you've seen.

I could explain it all here but I found a handy graphic from Impressive Webs that explains it much better than I could.

You can find it here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/